# Publishing Unity Application on Windows Phone Store

Tags: windows, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I have successfully uploaded the application and other thing on store but stuck in one thing content certification issue. Is there any way to get these certificate easily like in Google play developer console. I am getting this error

> Content Policies: 11.11 Required Rating Certificates
>
> If a rating under any particular rating system is required by law in
>   any country, you must assign a rating to your app. If applicable law
>   also requires documentation, include the rating documentation for that
>   rating system along with your app.
>
> Locations: Metadata
>
> Notes To Developer
>
> The app is a game that targets Korea and/or Brazil and/or Russia for
>   distribution, but does not have a valid game rating certificate.

I also try to go to theses certification site but didn't get any help from them. I am new in windows store. Kindly tell me the easiest possible way to resolve this issue. Thank you.

Comment: I have the same issue. Looking forward for an answer for this one!

Comment: I am also having this issue so I am providing bounty to the one who answers adequately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have same content certification issue with my game.

Because the market-specific age ratings are optional in most markets, though there are four markets where the age rating is required to publish an app/game: *Brazil, Korea, Russia and Taiwan*.

Using following steps got certification for each market where a rating is required:

1. Game ratings in **Brazil**
   Obtain a ESRB game rating using the online form-
   link-https://autoratingtool.esrb.org/ARTclient/Windows.aspx
2. Game ratings in **Russia**
   obtain the rating-
   link-http://apps.pegi.eu/
3. Game ratings in **South Korea**
   Korea requires all games to be rated using the GRAC system.
   link-http://www.grb.or.kr/Institution/EtcForm01.aspx
4. Game ratings in **Taiwan**
   register as a developer with CSRR (typically takes a few days) and then register your game with CSRR through their website.
   link-http://www.gamerating.org.tw/company_login.php

At last after you have your ratings and certificates, and have added them to the app submission.

Comment: Very helpful... Thank you :)

Comment: also see this link re: GRAC https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/095f8d18-2058-4498-9991-7679cd8635f8/how-can-i-apply-game-rating-certificate-on-south-korea-grac?forum=wpsubmit

Comment: and this https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/07/02/submitting-apps-with-age-ratings-in-the-unified-dev-center/

Answer (score 3):

I've published a social app for Windows Store. I've just set "16+" for all countries (because according to descriptions in Windows Store my app should be 16+), and my app is available in Russia without special rating assignment.
I'm sure that you can do the same.

Comment: 16+ for all countries or 16+ just for Russia?

Comment: For all countries. I've just corrected brackets order in my answer. Now it should look more clear

Comment: And whats about kids games?

Comment: You can read description of every category and set the appropriate category. Did you do the same on Google Play? Or there were other person who assigned the rating for your app?

Comment: @Schullz it takes only 2 minutes in Google Play for content rating for all countries. And its very easy on Google play more than you think .I think Windows store need to be upgrade their content rating method.