# Age Rating Issues when Publishing to the Windows Store Using Unity3D

Tags: windows, certificate, store, rating

I have a small issue with a game that I published to the Windows App Store using Unity3D.

After a few submissions, my game passed certification and is now on the store. However, I noticed that in my submission it shows the following "failures":

**Content Policies**: 11.11 Required Rating Certificates
If a rating under any particular rating system is required by law in any country, you must assign a rating to your app. If applicable law also requires documentation, include the rating documentation for that rating system along with your app.

**Locations**: Metadata

**Notes To Developer**
The app is a game that targets Korea and/or Brazil and/or Russia for distribution, but does not have a valid game rating certificate.

My game does not target Korea, Brazil, or Russia for distribution, but I still get this message. Is there something I'm missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have Taiwan?
Coz, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32602757/publishing-unity-application-on-windows-phone-store) there are four markets where the age rating is required to publish an app/game: Brazil, Korea, Russia and Taiwan.

Check that post, it is very helpful. Or you can set age group to 16+, then I also I think no certificate is needed by any country.

Best of luck.